How can I use push() with router.post to populate a subdocument with contents from an HTML form?
I'm making a fitness log MEN CRUD app and am trying to push data to a MongoDB subdocument using an HTML form. When adding (creating) a new workout, the user is presented with two options between 'run' or 'weight training'. The button selection takes the user to a form to fill in relevant data like date, time, distance.
I'm able to create each workout, but the data is 'null'.
Models:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const RunSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  time: Number,
  distance: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

const WeightliftingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      time: Number,
      exercise: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
      },
      notes: String,
      });
      
const workoutSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
  run: RunSchema,
  weightTraining: WeightliftingSchema,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  workouts: [workoutSchema],
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;

Routers:
router.get('/new', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('workouts/new.ejs')
})

router.get('/new/run', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('workouts/new/run.ejs')
})

router.get('/new/weightlifting', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('workouts/new/weightlifting.ejs')
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.session.user._id);
        currentUser.workouts.push(req.body)
        await currentUser.save();
        res.redirect(`/users/${currentUser._id}/workouts`)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.redirect('/')
    }
})

router.post('/:workoutId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.session.user._id);
        const workout = currentUser.workouts.id(req.params.workoutId);
        currentUser.workout.run.push(req.body)
        res.redirect('workouts/show.ejs', { workout: workout })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.redirect('/')
    }
})

HTML form:
    <form action="/users/<%= user._id %>/workouts" method="POST">
        <label for="date">date:</label>
        <input type="number" id="date" name="date"/>
        
        <label for="time">time:</label>
        <input type="number" id="time" name="time"/>
        
        <label for="distance">distance:</label>
        <input type="number" id="distance" name="distance"/>
        
        <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
    </form>

What I'm going for:
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  workouts: [
    run: [
     date: DATA FROM FORM
     time: DATA FROM FORM
     distance: DATA FROM FORM
   ]
    weightTraining: [null]
  ],
});

Edit (adding server.js):
dotenv.config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const session = require('express-session');


/* ------------------------------- CONTROLLERS ------------------------------ */
const authController = require('./controllers/auth.js');
const workoutsController = require('./controllers/workouts.js');
const passUserToView = require('./middleware/pass-user-to-view.js');
const isSignedIn = require('./middleware/is-signed-in.js');

const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : '3000';

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log(`Connected to MongoDB ${mongoose.connection.name}.`);
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
// app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

/* --------------------------------- ROUTES --------------------------------- */
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', {
    user: req.session.user,
  });
});

app.use(passUserToView);
app.use('/auth', authController);
app.use(isSignedIn);
app.use('/users/:userId/workouts', workoutsController);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The express app is ready on port ${port}!`);
});

I've tried a number of things including:

changing routes
changing the form action


User.workouts is an array of objects with a run key and a weightTraining key which are also both arrays. You would need to push the req.body to currentUser.workouts[index].run or currentUser.workouts[index].weightTraining. However, are you sure run and weightTraining should be arrays too, that doesn't seem right? Have you decided how you will determine if the data being sent is for a run or a weight training? Looking at your schema you could check if(req.body.distance) then you know it's for a run.

You're right. I think run and weightTraining should be objects?
I'll try adding workouts[index] for the push()

If you want run and weightTraining to be objects then update your workoutSchema such that run: RunSchema,  weightTraining: WeightliftingSchema, then you should be able to to do currentUser.workouts.push({run: req.body})

I've updated run: and weightTraining to be objects. I've also updated the router to include currentUser.workotus.push({run: req.body}) and await currentUser.save() and still not able to push. I think I may still be missing something

Should it be workouts not workotus? Also, make sure req.body is being parsed. Just console.log(req.body). You will also have to clear the user from the database if it has the previous data structure of arrays.

Yes. Apologies, that was a typo. I had currentUser.workouts.push({run: req.body}). I also added console.log(req.body) and interestingly it didn't return anything.

this is my updated router:
const currentUser = await User.findById(req.session.user._id);
const workout = currentUser.workouts.id(req.params.workoutId)
workout.run.push(req.body)
await workout.save();

Where have you mounted the router? Show your app.js . Also what body parser are you using e.g app.use(express.json()); and app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Added server.js to original post. Thanks for the help.

Things are getting a bit messey. Try to establish if you are posting to the correct route by doing console.log('req.body in /users/:userId/workouts =', req.body) inside that post route handler. That will tell you if the route caught the request and what the body looks like. Then once you query the database for the user do a console.log('currentUser =', currentUser); and post the output so we can see what currentUser fields look like.
